# Android emulator and OpenGL ES failure

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I try to understand how works emulator for android.
I use adt bundle (Eclipse).
Yesterday emulator launched with error,
changing ram, heap size, re-creating, restarting allowed to run emulator.
After restarting of computer today - emulator stop run again. The same error 0x3005 - OpenGlES.
Console:

```
 Android Launch!
 adb is running normally.
 Performing com.android0.MainActivity activity launch
 Automatic Target Mode: Preffered AVD 'em10' is not available. Launching new emulator.
 Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'em10'
 Failed to create Context 0x3005
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wgGetExtensionsStringARB
 emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

....
In finish application launched and worked.
Why I have received these errors? How to evitate them?
Thanks.

Comment: check if gpu emulation is enabled on you emulated device

Comment: already checked. it doesn't depend. I need to be sure that it will start each time. It is very difficult do something when it need to waste 90% of time to start emulator

Comment: Maybe check no emulator processes are already running in your task list?